# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property - on getInstanceById

Tags: javascript, jquery

This site I have up for staging here: http://graysonearle.com/hosted/signified/ has a problem: When it loads, there are supposed to be red dots that appear (five of them) at some random intersections of the triangles. However, it appears that things are not loading in the correct order and so I'm left with this cannot read property error.

How can I be sure that both the JSON object and the sketch element have loaded before executing the 'addPerson' function? The error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPerson' of undefined"

```
var p; // sketch id
// see if sketch canvas has loaded before doing anything
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#sketch').length) {

        clearInterval(checkExist);
        p = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');

        $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
            // load in JSON data to processing sketch
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                p.addPerson(data[i]);
            }
        }).done(function() {
            // callback

        });

    }
}, 100); // check again if not loaded...
```

and the addPerson code:

```
function addPerson(var json) {
  // get random coordinate from the stack
  int rando = floor(random(intersections.size()));
  PVector pv = (PVector) intersections.get(rando);

  // add new node with coordinate and json data fed from index.html js call
  nodes.add(new Node(pv, json.Name, json.Location, json.Details, json.PhotoURL, json.Vimeo));

  // delete coord after using!
  intersections.remove(rando); // bye bye! no two nodes should have same loc
}
```

Comment: Show `getInstanceById()` method.

Comment: Your site shows `uncaught exception: Multiple calls to size() for 3D renders are not allowed.` error in Firebug.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPerson' of undefined` in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: You're not using `this` anywhere in your `addPerson` function. How is it supposed to operate on `p` then?